# Will using a large local video file with React Player affect site loading speed in NextJS?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-player

I realise this is almost certainly a very stupid question, but my brain's not working and I really need to know the answer. I have a React/NextJS site on which I would like to show a rather large video file, over 20mb probably, using react-player. The video file will be stored in Next's /public folder, as it should be. Will having such a large file as part of my site slow down its loading time, bundle size, affect Lighthouse scores etc? Or will [react-player](https://github.com/CookPete/react-player) 'stream' the file after the initial page load?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @antonwilhelm Well, the page I'm using now has eight videos on it using React Player, ranging from 8mb to 45mb each. I've just tested the page in Google Lighthouse and it scored 99 on performance, so it seems they're 'streamed' and not part of the initial page load.